# Automount webdav server on startup with internet

Tags: arch-linux, automounting, davfs2

**What I am trying to do?**

making the `https://dav.example.com/` automount on startup and without asking user credentials.

**what steps I've undertaken?**
I followed [official archlinux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Davfs) to setup my davs
steps:

- installed davfs2
- added myself to group "network":
  `usermod -a -G network myusername`
- added webdav server to `/etc/fstab`:

`https://webdav.example.com /home/username/webdav davfs user,noauto,uid=username,file_mode=600,dir_mode=700 0 1`

- created secret file in my `/home/username/` and added credentials:
  `mkdir ~/.davfs2/

  echo "https://webdav.example.com webdavuser webdavpassword" >> ~/.davfs2/secrets

   chmod 0600 ~/.davfs2/secrets`
- mounted my dav
  `mount ~/MyDav`

**what happens?**
When restart my pc and when startup has been completed I open nautilus but webdav server is not mounted. I have to mount it manually from the terminal on each restart. This is normal because I set `noauto` in fstab line. However, If I set `auto` instead, it will mount but fail in the process and return error on boot because mounting require internet connection therefore return error "failed mounting". So both `auto` and `noauto` have the same results for me.
What I need now is to make webdav server automount when internet connection has been established.
some suggested using `_netdev` on fstab line. I did, but no change.
Maybe worthmentioning that when I run `mount ~/MyWebDav` from the terminal it mount without asking credintials, but when run `mount -a` it ask for credintials and mount if they are correct.

I need to make the webdav server `https://dav.example/` automount on startup only when internet connection has been occurred.

Comment: You said you tried the `_netdev` option, can you post exactly what you tried?

Comment: nevermind friend. I just fixed it somehow. I enabled `NetworkManager-wait-online.service` , and set `noauto` to the fstab line... this solution for who search google and find this question. also do not forget to copy secrets file from /etc/davfs2/secrets to ~/.davfs2/secrets...and not just creating it instead because it won't work. and insert you keys in the copied file.

Comment: also do not forget to make group `davfs2` and add yourself to it, reboot pc, and should work. also I followed this guide https://doc.owncloud.org/server/latest/user_manual/files/access_webdav.html

Comment: Glad you got it worked out, feel free to post your solution as an answer.

Comment: @Stephanrog As fooot says, please consider posting an explanation of your solution as an answer to your own question (and accept it as a correct answer) as users might not read the comments